# Apache Rewrite - Allow php filetype

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?id=$1&n=$2 [L]
```

This rule will write `website.com/4/name` to

> /index.php?id=4&n=name

How can I add/change the rule to stop calls to `website.com/blog/login.php` from rewriting?

**Answer**

Per Shane's comment, and looking closer at the regex:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?id=$1&n=$2 [L]
```

**1 First Expression**

**^([^/]*)**

```
^   = start string
( ) = group
[ ] = match
^   = not "/"
*   = 0 or more of the preceding
```

**2 slash**
/

**3 Repeat previous expression**
([^/]*)

**4 end string $**

So to keep /blog/ from rewriting: match lowercase letters in the first expression [a-z]

**Final Rule**

```
RewriteRule ^([^/a-z]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?id=$1&n=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Is that the only thing that you ever want to avoid rewriting?  Or, do you have some specific rules around things that should be rewritten (like those where the 'id' is a number)?

Comment: At the moment, it should allow php files in the /blog/ directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a rule before your current one that will prevent rewriting the files that you want to leave alone.

```
RewriteRule ^blog/.*\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?id=$1&n=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Your answer looks good too. See mine above.